# Finding the probability formula of minimum of 2 fair dice question

Tags: probability

Suppose there are *k* dice thrown. Let *M* denote the minimum of the *k* numbers rolled.

I've learned that finding the individual probability is:

$$P(M = m) = P(M \ge m) - P(M \ge m + 1) $$

Can someone please explain this to me? I've tried plugging in values for $m = 1, ... , 6$ but it isn't clear to me how that formula is derived.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking: are you asking about the minimum of two dice or about the equality that you posted? Notice that $\Pr[M\ge m]=\sum_{k=m}^{6}\Pr[M=k]$.

Comment: I am asking about the equality that I posted. In my textbook, it gave that the individual probability of finding the minimum of a certain m is P(M = m) = P(M >= m) - P(M >= m + 1)

Comment: It will help you to look at my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623003/what-defines-a-description-of-a-probability-distribution/1623032#1623032).

Answer (score 5):

How can the minimum be $\ge m$? There are two possibilities: (i) the minimum is exactly $m$ or (ii) the minimum is greater than $m$.

The minimum is greater than $m$ precisely if the minimum is $\ge m+1$.

The possibilities (i) and (ii) are disjoint, so $$\Pr(M\ge m)=\Pr(M=m)+\Pr(M\ge m+1).$$
From this we get immediately
$$\Pr(M=m)=\Pr(M\ge m)-\Pr(M\ge m+1).$$

*Remark*: The above deals with your specific question. But to finish your problem, note that the minimum is $\ge w$ precisely if all the values are $\ge w$. And for $w=1,2,\dots, 6$ the tosses are all $\ge w$ with probability $\left(\frac{7-w}{6}\right)^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$$
\Pr[M \geq m] = \sum_{i=m+1}^\infty Pr[M = i]
$$
because if $M \geq m$, then either $M=m$ or $M=m+1$ or $M=m+2$ or $M=m+3$ or ...
(by the way, the infinite sum exists because it is bounded above by 1)

Similarly, 
$$
\Pr[M \geq (m+1)] = \sum_{i=(m+1)+1}^\infty Pr[M = i]
$$
because if $M \geq (m+1)$, then either $M=m+1$ or $M=m+2$ or $M=m+3$ or ...

Now, you subtract, and what do you get?
$$
\Pr[M \geq (m+1)] - \Pr[M \geq m] = \Pr[M = m] 
$$

So that sum is easy. Even the problem is, but I'll write a separate answer for that.

Comment: Given that a question was asked about it, the *equality* is obviously not obvious, and saying that it is is probably not very encouraging.

Comment: Answer changed.